# Webpack (with React) hot loading not working

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I have setup hot reloading with `react-hot-loader`. In the console it looks like it works, but browser does not actually reload. Why is this?

[image]

Ignore the errors, I think they come from a plugin. It correctly detects I change App.jsx but the browser does not update unless I do a full refresh.

My webpack.config.js below:

```
const path = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

const context = path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
const {dependencies} = require("./package.json")

module.exports = {
  context,
  entry: {
    vendor: Object.keys(dependencies),
    app: [
      "react-hot-loader/patch",
      "./js/index.js"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    filename: "[name]-[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          plugins: [
            [
              "react-css-modules",
              {
                context
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            'postcss-loader'
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor"
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "index.html"
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("css/[name].css")
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  devtool: "eval"
}
```

**`index.js`**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import React from "react"
import {AppContainer} from "react-hot-loader"
import App from "./App.jsx"

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <AppContainer>
      <Component />
    </AppContainer>,
    document.getElementById("app")
  )
}

render(App)

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept("./App.jsx", () => render(App))
}
```

Comment: Did you add `react-hot-loader/babel` plugin?

Comment: @Thai, I just tried adding that in `.babelrc`, but same issue. It worked yest on my office comp :( but I was fixing the config for a build and this issue happened ...